# SFDX project create error

Tags: salesforcedx

I am getting this error, while creating a project. What could be the reason?

```
$ sfdx force:project:create -n mysfdxproj
 !    Unexpected token '<' at 7:1 in ..\package.json
 !    <!DOCTYPE html>
 !
```

Comment: You got an HTML file instead of a JSON file. Let me check real quick.

Comment: Try updating your CLI: `sfdx update`, then try your request again.

Comment: $ sfdx update
sfdx-cli: Updating CLI... already on latest version: 6.0.9-3391781
sfdx-cli: Updating plugins... done

Comment: @sfdcfox, I already have the updated one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with D drive. I tried creating workspace in C drive, everything works great. However the error was unclear, and somehow figured it out.